# OLAP and Data Mining. How ?

Tags: data-mining, olap

For the final project of my computer class we have a paper to write which will be 20 percent of our final grade. I got assigned data mining without some specifics. So, I asked my teacher and he said I should research OLAP and Excel. So I did. But the thing is, we're only currently taking databases and such, and now I feel the need to learn them on my own.

So my questions:

- How can I use OLAP with Excel ?
- Where can I learn about data mining (books, and reliable websites) ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google for "Data Mining Book" and "OLAP Excel"

Comment: I do like the fact that you are upfront about needing help for your homework.

Answer (score 3):

You can look on Palo Olap.

http://palo.net/

It has plugin for excel and also support for linux/windows.